# Запрос json для заполнения справочника

Tags: c#, json, json-encode, c#-8.0

Нужно заполнить справочник запросом json
Вот пример с оф сайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{
"Items":[{
    "Data":{
        "Items":[{
            "Data":{
                "Items":null,
                "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
            },
            "DataArray":[{
                "Items":null,
                "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
            }],
            "Name":"Строковое содержимое",
            "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
        }],
        "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
    },
    "DataArray":[{
        "Items":[{
            "Data":{
                "Items":null,
                "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
            },
            "DataArray":[{
                "Items":null,
                "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
            }],
            "Name":"Строковое содержимое",
            "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
        }],
        "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
    }],
    "Name":"Строковое содержимое",
    "Value":"Строковое содержимое"
}],
"Value":"Строковое содержимое"
```

}

сам справочник
[image: Справочник]

Ну и собственно мои попытки

```
"
                           ""Items"":
                            [
                                {

                                    ""Data"":
                                        {
                                            ""Items"":
                                              [
                                                    {
                                                        ""Data"":
                                                        {
                                                        ""Items"":null,
                                                        ""Value"":Строковое содержимое
                                                        },

                                                        ""DataArray"":
                                                        [
                                                            {
                                                                ""Items"":null,
                                                                ""Value"":[]

                                                            }
                                                        ],

                                                    ""Name"":IdTelegram,
                                                    ""Value"":"+chatid+ @"

                                                    }
                                               ],
                                            {
                                                        
                                               ],
                                                ""Value"":Строковое содержимое

                                           },
                                    ""DataArray"":
                                    [
                                        {
                                           ""Items"":
                                            [
                                                {
                                                    ""Data"":
                                                    {
                                                        ""Items"":null,
                                                        ""Value"":Строковое содержимое

                                                    },
                                                    ""DataArray"":
                                                    [
                                                        {
                                                            ""Items"":null,
                                                            ""Value"":[]

                                                        }
                                                    ],
                                                    ""Name"":IdUserElma,
                                                    ""Value"":" + IdUser+@"

                                                }
                                            ],
                                            ""Value"":Строковое содержимое

                                        }
                                    ],
                                    ""Name"":AuthToken,
                                    ""Value"":Строковое содержимое

                                }
                            ],
                            ""Value"":Строковое содержимое";
```

Классы:

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Item11> Items { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class DataArray
{
    public object Items { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Item11
{
    public Data Data { get; set; }
    public List<DataArray> DataArray { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Root11
{
    public List<Item11> Items { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Строка, которая приходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что это за обрывок текста в конце и от чего он? Не вижу вопроса в этом вопросе.

Comment: Это тело запроса для заполнения справочника elma 3.1 http://127.0.0.1:8000/API/REST/Entity/Insert/{}

Comment: Не понимаю, как он может помочь ответить на ваш вопрос. А в чём кстати вопрос?

Comment: Это веб запрос на добавление записи в справочник, но чтобы запрос прошел как надо ему нужно прописать тело запроса. Сам вопрос в том, где я должен в теле указать название столбца и значение, которое в него записать

Comment: Создайте модель данных, например вставкой вашего json-примера "как классы" в Visual Studio, дальше создайте объекты, наполните данными и сериализуйте в строку с использованием `JsonSerializer`. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to, затем отправьте строку на сервер с использованием `HttpClient`.

Comment: Вот классы, из них в Item11 name - это столбец , value - это значение, но в примере и другие поля из других классов должны быть чем то заполнены, но чем

Comment: Нн вставляйте код в комментарии, редактирйте сам пост. Невозможно читать же.

Comment: Хорошо, вставил в пост

Comment: Вам уже ответили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("DataArray")]
    public List<DataArray> DataArray { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class DataArray
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Items")]
    public Item Items { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Для сериализации/десереализации используйте [System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-6.0)

Пример:

```
var json = "";//тут наш длинный json
var instance = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
```

Изменяете как-либо instance и обратно сериализуете. Затем с помощью [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) отправляете запрос

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(instance);
var content = new StringContent(json , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content); //отправляем json
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //если сервер как-нибудь должен отвечать, то так можно "извлечь" этот ответ
```

Comment: Только строка, которая приходит (instance) отличается от строки на добавление, т.е. значение не занесется. В пост прикрепил строку instance

Comment: Разобрался в чем была проблема, нехватка времени, чтобы записать данные